# How do you use type arguments in a Spring Data custom method implementation?

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Per the Spring Data Commons [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.single-repository-behaviour), adding a custom method implementation to a Spring Data repository is quite simple:

```
interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    public void someCustomMethod(User user);
}

class UserRepositoryCustomImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {
    public void someCustomMethod(User user) {
        // Your custom implementation
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>,
        UserRepositoryCustom {
}
```

However, what I can't figure out is, what if you want to use the type arguments? For example:

```
interface SearchableRepository<T> {
    public Page<T> search(String query, Pageable page);
}

class SearchableRepositoryImpl<T> implements SearchableRepository<T> {
    public Page<T> search(String query, Pageable page) {
        // Right here, I need the Class<T> of T so that I can create
        // the JPA query
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>,
        SearchableRepository<User> {
}

public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long>,
        SearchableRepository<Article> {
}
```

In the implementation for that `search` method, I need to know the `Class<T>` of the supplied type argument `T` so that I can create the JPA query. I don't want to [add custom behavior to all repositories](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories), because I don't want all repositories to be searchable. I only want to apply the `SearchableRepository` interface to select repositories.

So how can you do this? Or can you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add Class to SearchableRepositoryImpl and in NewsRepositoryImpl inject (or create) a `new SearchableRepositoryImpl(Article.class)`

```
    class SearchableRepositoryImpl<T> implements SearchableRepository<T> {
      private Class<T> klass;
      public SearchableRepositoryImpl(Class<T> klazz){
        this.klass = klazz;
      }

      public Page<T> search(String query, Pageable page) {
            // Right here, I need the Class<T> of T so that I can create
            // the JPA query
        }
    }

    class NewsRepositoryImpl<Article> implements NewsRepository<Article> 
    {
      private SearchableRepository<Article> searchRepo = new SearchableRepositoryImpl(Article.class);
      public Page<T> search(String query, Pageable page){
        // delegate
        return searchRepo.search(query, page);
      }
}
```

Maybe `new SearchableRepositoryImpl` is not really spring best pratice, but just to show the idea

Comment: Ahhh. I misunderstood how the customization worked. This cleared the whole thing up for me. Thanks!

Comment: I added a more complete solution below that doesn't require the `new` as you showed. It's more Spring-y. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Bellabax's answer was right and got me on the right track, so he gets the kudos and the credit for the right answer. But for those stumbling across this question, here's a more complete implementation that auto-discovers the domain type and doesn't require calling `new` anything, and will hopefully be helpful to someone.

SearchableRepository.java

```
public interface SearchableRepository<T> {
    public Page<T> search(String query, Pageable page);
}
```

AbstractDomainClassAwareRepository.java

```
class AbstractDomainClassAwareRepository<T> {
    protected final Class<T> domainClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected AbstractDomainClassAwareRepository() {
        Type genericSuperclass = this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        while(!(genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType))
        {
            if(!(genericSuperclass instanceof Class))
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to determine type " +
                        "arguments because generic superclass neither " +
                        "parameterized type nor class.");
            if(genericSuperclass == AbstractDomainClassAwareRepository.class)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to determine type " +
                        "arguments because no parameterized generic superclass " +
                        "found.");

            genericSuperclass = ((Class)genericSuperclass).getGenericSuperclass();
        }

        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType)genericSuperclass;
        Type[] arguments = type.getActualTypeArguments();
        this.domainClass = (Class<T>)arguments[0];
    }
}
```

AbstractSearchableJpaRepository.java

```
class AbstractSearchableJpaRepository<T>
        extends AbstractDomainClassAwareRepository<T>
        implements SearchableRepository<T> {
    @PersistenceContext protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Page<T> search(String query, Pageable page) {
        // use this.domainClass to reference domain class
    }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>,
        SearchableRepository<User> { }
```

UserRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class UserRepositoryImpl extends AbstractSearchableJpaRepository<User> { }
```

NewsRepository.java

```
public interface NewsRepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long>,
        SearchableRepository<Article> { }
```

NewsRepositoryImpl.java

```
public class NewsRepositoryImpl extends AbstractSearchableJpaRepository<Article> { }
```